# Add a subprocess to another one

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.5

I would like to add a new subprocess to an existing subprocess.

I do not want a parallel execution of both processes, I just want to add the new subprocess (qpdf: which suppose to linearize the output pdf from pdfjam) to the existing one (pdfjam: which adds several pdf together), s. code below, but the newly added subprocess has not been executed, only the existing one.

How can I fix this?

This is the concerning part of the code:

```
tmp_pdf_file = tmpdir + "/" + basename + ".pdf"
if os.path.exists(tmp_pdf_file):
    subprocess.call(["pdfjam", "--keepinfo", "--noautoscale", "true", "--frame", "true", tmp_pdf_file, "-o", target_file_a4], cwd=tmpdir)  # existing subprocess
    self.progress.step()
    subprocess.call(["qpdf", "--linearize", target_file_a4, target_file_a4], cwd=tmpdir)  # new subprocess
    self.progress.step()
    shutil.move(tmp_pdf_file, target_file)
else:
    print("No pdf file generated!")
```

**Edit:** I think the second subprocess has difficulties to find `target_file_a4`, even though there is no error message.

**Edit2:** The code runs through without any error message (I am not quite sure if I am able to implement the suggest `communicate` due to my few python skills). I check if the output pdf is linearized by `pdfinfo foobar.pdf`, which gives me `Optimized: no` = linearized: no, see [manpage](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdfinfo1.html).

**Edit3:** The output is: `Extract init b"----\n  pdfjam: This is pdfjam version 2.08.\n  pdfjam: Reading any site-wide or user-specific defaults...\n (none found)\n  pdfjam: Effective call for this run of pdfjam:\n          /usr/bin/pdfjam --keepinfo --noautoscale 'true' --frame 'true' --outfile /path/to/foobar.pdf -- /tmp/extract-5j70hk9o/foobar.pdf - \n  pdfjam: Calling pdfinfo...\n pdfjam: Calling pdflatex...\n  pdfjam: Finished.  Output was to '/path/to/foobar.pdf'.\n" b'/path/to/foobar.pdf (object 579 0, file position 7769200): EOF while reading token\n'`

I might add that I use python 3.5.0.

**Edit4:**

I did my research this morning and have to comment that I have added the code snippet of cmidi to both subprocess, to the one with `pdfjam` and to the one with `qpdf`. When I did it only with the first subprocess than I received the same message as posted in **Edit3** without the `b'/path/to/foobar.pdf (object 579 0, file position 7769200): EOF while reading token\n'` line.

`Pdfjam` works fine (since the output pdf is one complete; `pdflatex` creates several separate ones). It clearly has to do with `qpdf`, see [here](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/issues/36).

[image]

Comment: Can you use `Popen` constructor to create the subprocess and subsequently use `communicate` method on the instance to print the error and post it here?
You should anyways use the communicate process to make your main process block on the first subprocess and only execute the second after the first is finished if running in parallel is not required

Comment: What behaviour do you observe, and in what way does this differ from what you wanted?

Comment: skyking, I just added another edit to answer your question.

Comment: subprocess error would not cause the main process errors until you are checking for them
try the below code `handle = subprocess.Popen(["pdfjam", "--keepinfo", "--noautoscale", "true", "--frame", "true", tmp_pdf_file, "-o", target_file_a4], cwd=tmpdir, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

followed by 
`out,err = handle.communicate()` `print err` on the processes.
Here is the manual
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Thank you very much, cmidi! This has helped a lot and facilitated the process of getting it done for me. Please, see **Edit3** above for the answer.

Comment: the output says that `pdfjam` has failed. And therefore your question is: "how to make `pdfjam` work?" that it is unrelated to the current question title ("add subprocess...")

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Please, see **edit4** for my answer.

Comment: So do you mean to say that blocking for the first process to complete and execute the second subprocess to completion with blocking communicate call, after the completing the first solved your problem ?or does the problem still exists ?

Comment: The `pdfjam` subprocess is totally fine. The `qpdf` subprocess fails. I found that `qpdf` has issues to linearize a pdf and to saved it on top of the same pdf. So `qpdf --linearize foobar.pdf foobar.pdf` fails with the error: `EOF while reading token`. My issue is that I do not know python well enough to implement the `qpdf` subprocess so that it functions. This `subprocess.call(["qpdf", "--linearize", target_file_a4, target_file_02], cwd=tmpdir)` still fails. I changed the second name to `target_file_02` which I define as `target_file_02 = tmpdir + "/" + basename + ".pdf"` but it stills fails